# Elegant way to store non unique key and non unique value

Tags: java, collections

So what would be elegant way to store key -- value if both are non unique, i need fifo but with option to access pair that was added as Nth. As far as I know maps won't do. I tought about using tab/list of two lists that would be key -- value determined by index but it doesn't sound "clean".

Comment: Yea You are right, that sounds way cleaner. I just had flip-flops on my eyes- wanted to use appropriate collection. Thank you!

Comment: OK I'll post that as the answer for you to accept. Hope that is the correct way as I'm quite new here.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds not like a map entry but more like `Pair<A, B>` in which case, you need that as a custom class since there's no tuple/pair class in the JRE. The JRE `Stack` class will give you fifo that you can also treat as a `List`